# Replacing words within a matrix in R

Tags: r, text, matrix

I have a matrix.  A single data entry in the matrix is a character string. For example, "crocin tablet".  The matrix contains many entries with "tablet" at the end.  I want to replace the word "tablet" with "tab" for every entry within the matrix. How can I do that in R?

Comment: `gsub("tablet", "tab", yourdata)`?

Comment: @Rob, I think this is so simple a question that there's no need for additional info. Ananda's comment nails it.

Comment: Agree, just deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just making Ananda Mahto's solution more explicit.

```
> newMatrix <- matrix(data=c("Abbott Laboratories tablet",
+                            "AbbVie tablet",
+                            "Acadia Pharmaceuticals tablet",
+                            "Acorda Therapeutics tablet",
+                            "Actavis tablet",
+                            "Actelion tablet",
+                            "Advanced Chemical Industries tablet",
+                            "Advaxis tablet",
+                            "Ajanta Pharma tablet",
+                            "Alcon tablet"), nrow=5, ncol = 2)
> gsub("tablet", "tab", newMatrix)
     [,1]                         [,2]                              
[1,] "Abbott Laboratories tab"    "Actelion tab"                    
[2,] "AbbVie tab"                 "Advanced Chemical Industries tab"
[3,] "Acadia Pharmaceuticals tab" "Advaxis tab"                     
[4,] "Acorda Therapeutics tab"    "Ajanta Pharma tab"               
[5,] "Actavis tab"                "Alcon tab"
```